# Is there a way to scaffold a database on application launch with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a web form that pulls information from a database. Every 90 days this database is updated with new tables. Instead of having to manually go into the code and scaffolding is there a way I can update my application with a scaffold on a set schedule?

Comment: How would you use the new tables without changing your code?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I did not think that far and now I have to figure that out first. Thanks!